# How to install the brotli nginx module properly on debian

Tags: linux, nginx, apt, compression, amazon-lightsail

I'm trying to setup brotly compression on a `nginx/1.10.3` server running on `Debian 9.5 Stretch / Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u5` (on a 
 lightsail instance). I used the following commands to try to install it:

```sh
$ sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:hda-me/nginx-stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install brotli nginx nginx-module-brotli
```

Unfortunatly the first one fails:

```
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpwhmks25f/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpwhmks25f/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 1F5EB010C5341279: public key "Launchpad PPA for hda_launchpad" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

which causes that the package cannot be installed, so running the last command (after `suto apt-get update`) ends with that the package can't be found:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nginx-module-brotli
```

I'ved looked up several docs but there are only infos about installing it on CentOS or ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official Debian module for nginx *(not so far)*, but you can compile and add dynamic modules for Brotli compression.

What is dynamic module and how to configure it, read [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-open-source/#sources).

You can clone brotli modules from [here](https://github.com/eustas/ngx_brotli/) and compile it (see section "**Other Platforms - Dynamically loaded**" carefully).

Also [this guide](https://gorails.com/blog/how-to-compile-dynamic-nginx-modules) helped me understand what configure arguments I can remove *(spoiler: all dynamic modules, except brotli)*

You may need additional dependencies to compile (such as `libbrotli-dev` and others). *Look for another manuals in this direction.*